# Comprimir / compactar imagem após upload

Tags: php

Preciso de ajuda para aperfeiçoar um script.. Em geral quero adicionar a esse script:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'get_photo') {
        if(is_array($_FILES)) {
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
                $file_name = $_FILES['userImage']['name'];
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
                preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $file_name, $ext);

                // Gera um nome único para a imagem
                $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
                // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
                $desired_dir="../image/posts/";
                $caminho_imagem = $desired_dir.$nome_imagem;

                if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$caminho_imagem)) {
                    echo '<img src="/image/posts/'.$nome_imagem.'" width="100px" height="100px" />';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Um sistema ou forma de reduzir a qualidade da imagem, pois estou trabalhando em um site como o Instagram e preciso que as imagens fiquem bastante leve, com o Facebook faz. Captura a imagem e **converte** ela para **JPG** e reduz o tamanho da imagem cado seja **MB** para **KB**

Desde já agradeço a todos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja esse script, ele converte imagens para jpeg.

O parâmetro `imagemOriginal` é o caminho onde está a imagem original, o parâmetro `imagemFinal` é o nome final após a conversão e o parâmetro `qualidade` é um valor inteiro de 0 a 100, onde 0 é baixa qualidade e 100 qualidade máxima, quanto mais próximo de 100, mais "pesada" a imagem ficará.

```
function converterImagem($imagemOriginal, $imagemFinal, $qualidade) {
    // jpg, png, gif or bmp
    $exploded = explode('.',$imagemOriginal);
    $ext = $exploded[count($exploded) - 1]; 

    if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i',$ext))
        $imagemTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagemOriginal);
    else if (preg_match('/png/i',$ext))
        $imagemTmp=imagecreatefrompng($imagemOriginal);
    else if (preg_match('/gif/i',$ext))
        $imagemTmp=imagecreatefromgif($imagemOriginal);
    else if (preg_match('/bmp/i',$ext))
        $imagemTmp=imagecreatefrombmp($imagemOriginal);
    else
        return 0;

   // O parâmetro "qualidade" é um valor de 0 (baixa) até 100 (alta)
   imagejpeg($imagemTmp, $imagemFinal, $qualidade);
   imagedestroy($imagemTmp);

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Certo, usei um script parecido com esse, porem o script sera rodado na pasta **localweb\PROJETO\conn\server.php** e ele salva a imagem na mesma pasta onde o php foi rodado, quando preciso que ele mande para **localweb\PROJETO\image\posts\** , e outra usando o seu script, como pergundar se foi mandado para tal pasta como o meu `if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$caminho_imagem))`

Comment: @PedroQuezado esse script recebe como parâmetro o path para a imagem. Se você quer salvar a sua imagem em uma local diferente, utilize a função `move_uploaded_file` para mudar a imagem de diretorio, após muda-la de local, chame o script passando o diretorio atual da imagem.