# Converter o tamanho da imagem antes de fazer upload PHP

Tags: php

Colegas,

tenho um código do qual após o upload para o diretório, ele diminui a imagem e substitui a imagem do upload. Vejam:

```
$c = 0;
foreach($fotos['name'] as $foto){

$tempProd = $fotos['tmp_name'][$c++];
$extensoesProd = array('png', 'jpg');
$validarProd = pathinfo($fotosProd, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
list($nomeFotoProd,$extensaoFotoProd) = explode($validarProd,$fotosProd);
$nomeFotoProd = md5($nomeFotoProd).".".$validarProd;

if(move_uploaded_file($tempProd, '../../projeto-final/produtos/'.$nomeFotoProd)){

            $diretorioNormal = "../../projeto-final/produtos/";
            $fotoDir = $diretorioNormal.$nomeFotoProd;
            list($largura,$altura) = getimagesize($fotoDir);
            $novaLargura = 997;
            $novaAltura = 665;
            $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
            $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($fotoDir);
            imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura, $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);
            imagejpeg($miniatura,$fotoDir,90);
    ....
    }
}
```

Até aqui funciona corretamente, porém tem como converter a imagem antes de jogá-la para o servidor sem ter que fazer esse processo de subir e substituir?

Answer (score 1):

Pode conseguir isto com JavaScript ([Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) e [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)), exemplos:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63018/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145713/3635

Exemplo usando `Canvas`, `FileReader` e `Ajax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function compressImage(file, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, format, response) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    var reader = new FileReader();    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var width  = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        response(
            canvas.toDataURL("image/" + format).replace(/^data[:]image\/(.*);base64,/, "")
        );
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function uploadAjax(data, fileName, success, error)
{
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    oReq.open("POST", "upload.php?filename=" + fileName, true);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                success(oReq.responseText);
            } else {
                error(oReq.status);
            }
        }
    };
    oReq.send(data);
}

function enviar() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;

    //Gerar imagem com tamanho normal
    compressImage(filesToUpload[0], 800, 600, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filesToUpload[0].name, function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });

    //Gerar imagem com thumb
    compressImage(filesToUpload[0], 150, 150, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filesToUpload[0].name.replace(/\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/, "_thumb.$1"), function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });
}
</script>

<p>
    <input type="file" value="" id="input">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="send">
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('send').onclick = enviar;
</script>
```

O PHP deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php
define('PASTA_UPLOAD', '/home/user/projeto/data');

if (isset($_GET['filename']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $cl = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];

    $tmpFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '~upload-');

    $file = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');
    $fh   = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    if ($file && $fh) {
        $data = '';
        while (FALSE === feof($fh)) {
            $data .= fgets($fh, 256);
        }
        fwrite($file, base64_decode($data));
    }

    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($fh) {
        fclose($fh);
    }

    echo 'OK';
    copy($tmpFile, PASTA_UPLOAD . '/' . $_GET['filename']);
} else {
    echo 'Requisição inválida';
}
```

Também é possivel usando outras tecnologias como Flash e Java Applet, mas o npapi deixou de funcionar em muitos browsers e alguns browsers como chrome estão desabilitando o Flash por padrão.

Answer (score 0):

**Achei algo que pode te ajudar:**

[comprimir-compactar-imagem-upload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115370/comprimir-compactar-imagem-ap%C3%B3s-upload)

Mas basicamente, você precisa fazer um case para filtrar diferentes extensões e usar cada **imagecreatefrom*()** para sua respectiva extensão:

```
$imagemTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagemOriginal);
$imagejpeg($imagemTmp, $imagemFinal, $qualidade);
$imagedestroy($imagemTmp);
```

--

Caso você queira imagens com **nome único**, você terá problema. Use:

```
// Gera um identificador único para o arquivo
$nomeFotoProd = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).".".$validarProd;
```

Ao invés de:

```
$nomeFotoProd = md5($nomeFotoProd).".".$validarProd;
```

*(Se eu fizer o upload de uma imagem com nome igual ela vai ser substituída)*

Comment: A pergunta é: *porém tem como converter a imagem antes de jogá-la para o servidor sem ter que fazer esse processo de subir e substituir?*, não é um problema no PHP e sim na compressão da imagem na camada cliente-side.

Comment: Entendi, **concordo com você**, tive uma interpretação errada da pergunta haha. com relação a usar o flash eu nem o citaria pois alem de depreciação é um queijo suíço na segurança.

Comment: Só citei para ele entender a camada clientes-side ;) ... Flash realmente não traz mas nenhuma vantagem, no maximo como fallback. Até mais o/